# How to force compiler or interpreter to see binary numbers two's complement?

Tags: python, c++

This is a simple **C++** program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int x=0b10000001;
cout<<"Your number is :"<<x;
}
```

Output:

> Your number is : 129

This is its **Python** counterpart also:

```
>>> i=0b10000001
>>> print i
129
>>>
```

I want to know, how can I force the C compiler or Python interpreter to see my variable as a two's complement number and print `-127` instead of `129`?

I can write a function to do what I want (i.e. check the most significant bit and print the desired value), but I want to know, where numbers behaved as two's complement and when they behaved like a plain binary value in programming?

**The question is :**

**When binary variables behaved as a two's complement number and when they behaved as a plain binary number?**

Comment: Use `signed char` instead of `int`? (given that your device works that way)

Comment: Uh, in C/C++ you'd have to jump through a couple of hoops. Making it `signed char` and then converting that to `int` would work. By the way, your number in two's complement is not -1, it's -127.

Comment: @deviantfan That was good. I defined `x` as `char` / `signed char` and in the next line, I cast it to `int` before printing. and now I see `-127`. but the question is not, "how?", it is "why?"

Comment: @Abraham The overflow at 127+1==-128 happens if the variable is 8 bit long, but `int` is larger than that. It can hold larger numbers before it overflows. (Strictly speaking, the sizes depend on your device)

Comment: @Aracthor Not quite, integer literals are, unless otherwise specified (using e.g. suffixes) are of type `int`, which by default is signed.

Comment: NOTE: you have completely changed the question, and it doesn't match the title anymore.   If you have a new question, you should ask a new question rather than rendering the answers people supplied obsolete and confusing.

Comment: Your question still says you want `-1`. Do you disagree with `-127`?

Comment: @StefanPochmann, No, you are right. :)  I correct it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest no-casting way I know how:

```
i = i - 2*(i & (1 << 7))
```

where `i` is any integer type at least big enough for your target value, and where `7` should be replaced by the position of the sign bit (7 for 8-bit numbers, 15 for 16-bit numbers, etc.).

This works because the sign bit in a signed integer is best interpreted as being the *negative* of its usual value. For example, the sign bit of an 8-bit number means -128, not +128. This little snippet of code basically subtracts twice the sign bit's value, to turn +128 into -128.

Example from Python:

```
>>> i = 129
>>> i = i - 2*(i & (1 << 7))
>>> i
-127
```

---

When programming, the *type* of a value determines how that value's bit pattern will be interpreted by the program. An unsigned value interprets the bit pattern without any sign bit (so that values cannot be negative) while a signed value interprets it with a sign bit (in twos-complement). In C, the sign bit is the most significant bit of a fixed-width integer. By forcibly casting a value to a smaller size, you can change which bit is considered the sign bit; this is why printing

```
(signed char)129
```

in C will give you -127.

Note that Python does not have a built-in unsigned type; all integers are signed but they can be arbitrarily big (unlike C, where integers are constrained to fit in a specific number of bits). Thus, my answer shows you how to get a signed value without using casting; it is applicable both to C and Python.

Answer (score 1):

The binary representation of a negative number does not work the way you think. It is not a simple two's complement, if the sign-bit is set. So a sign-flip operation on a number is **not** just setting the sign-bit like `x ^= (1 << 7)`. Instead, the binary representation of a binary number is `x = ~x + 1`. If `x` is then interpreted as a signed integer, it will print the negative value, if however you treat the integer as `unsigned`, you will get `255 - x + 1`, whatever that may be.

For a bit width of 8bit, see this example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   int8_t x = 0b10000001;
   int8_t y = 0b11111111;
   std::cout << "x as signed int is :" << int(x) << '\n';  // prints -127
   std::cout << "x as unsigned is :  " << int(uint8_t(x)) << '\n'; // 129
   std::cout << "y as signed int is :" << int(y) << '\n';          // -1
   std::cout << "y as unsigned is :  " << int(uint8_t(y)) << '\n'; // 255
   uint8_t z = 1;
   std::cout << "z ^ (1 << 7) = " << int(int8_t(z ^ (1 << 7))) << '\n'; // -127
   std::cout << "~z + 1       = " << int(int8_t(~z + 1)) << '\n';       // -1
}
```

When printing the value to stdout, you have to cast it back to `int`, otherwise it will be interpreted as a `char` which will most likely be non-printable characters.

As `int8_t` is an extension of C++11, you have to compile this program with `--std=c++11`.

Comment: The `int8_t` is great, thanks. but I'm not agree with the first part of your answer. I tried to print `int x=0b11111111111111111111111111111111;` and it returns `-1`. So I think @Michel Billaud's answer is right. Are you agree? _Note that, integers have 4 bytes length in my computer_

Comment: Well, it depends on what you mean. If you treat x as an `int8_t`, its 8th bit is set and it is a negative number: `0b10000001`. If the same bit pattern were a 16bit number, it would look like `0b0000000010000001`. Of course, its signbit would be zero and hence a positive number. That's why you have to be so careful about how you cast the number. Anyway, my answer and his do not contradict.

Comment: I saved the binary number in an [signed]`int` variable. I thought they defined `int8_t` to have 8 bit integers with 8th bit as the sign bit instead of 32th bit in `int` variables.

Comment: `int8_t` does not simply put the signbit in another place. It means that it is a *short* int. It only uses 8bit and not 32 (or 64 on any recent system).

Answer (score 1):

The constant 0b10000001 has its eight bit set to one.

When loaded into a 32- ou 64-bit int variable `x` , the leftmost bit is 0 so it **is**  a positive value.

Comment: Exactly. I tried to save a 32 bit binary number in `x` and print it, and it behaved as a twos complement now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interesting way to do it in python:

```
>>> from struct import *
>>> i = 0b10000001
>>> print unpack('b', pack('B', i))[0]
-127
>>>
```

`pack()` returns a byte string representation of a number, based on a conversion code.

`pack('B', i)` gives `'\x81'`  IE the a single character byte string, the character is the one who's unsigned binary representation (specified by the 'B') is `10000001`

`unpack()` takes a byte string and turns it into a list of numbers, based on a conversion code for each byte.

`unpack('b', '\x81')` returns (-127), because that is what binary `10000001` means when interpreted as a signed binary char (which is what the 'b' specifies).

`[0]` is used to select the first (and only) element of the list returned by `unpack()`.

Comment: May I ask you to add a description please?

Comment: Sure - hope it makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

An expression just using the value once:

```
>>> (0b10000001 + 128) % 256 - 128
-127
```

Or (after seeing nneonneo's answer):

```
>>> i - (i >> 7 << 8)
-127
```

Comment: The mecanisme involved here is **sign extension**. When assigning a value from an `int_8` to a larger (signed) integer, the leftmost bit (sign) is transferred to *all* the extra left bits. So it keeps the intended meaning of the same number, represented on small or large ints.

Try with `int8_t x = 0b10000001; int y = x; cout << x;` which returns -127

Comment: In Python, `(i if i<128 else i-256)` seems simpler to me. Juste compare, and subtract.

Comment: @MichelBillaud Yeah, of course C has other options, I just did Python. I admit I didn't even think of if-else, I guess because I didn't want to repeat the value. Or because I'm just used to doing it the way I showed. I like yours, but personally, I still like mine better. Might depend on the actual code context, though.